# Collection_select rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, grouped-collection-select

I've a little issue with the has_many trough association. I've got 3 models User, Tag, Taggings. Here the code:

Users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #---------------------------------Associations---------------------------------------
  attr_accessor :login
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy , autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  #---------------------------------End Association------------------------------------
     #---------------------------------Tagging ----------------------------------------------
  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).users
  end

  def self.tag_counts
    Tag.select("tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
        joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id")
  end

  def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
  #---------------------------------End Tagging --------------------------------------------

end
```

Tags model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :users , through: :taggings
  validates :name , presence: true
end
```

Taggings model:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The Issue is, that I want to add a collection_select in my registration/edit view. But I have no idea, how I can do this on my own. I spent a lot of time to get an working solution. Anyway, I would be really glad and pleasure if someone could help me. I include only the appropriated code.

Once again here is my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Rechtsgebiete:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <%= f.collection_select :tag_list, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true, class: 'form-control'} %>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Registration Controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  after_filter :send_welcome_mail, only: :create

  def update     #TODO fix the avatar uploade
    if params[:user].present?
      new_params = params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :admin, :approved, :tag_list, profile_attributes: [:anrede, :titel,  :vorname, :nachname, :user_id, :kanzlei, :kanlei_nr, :straße, :straße_nr, :plz, :stadt, :land, :telefon, :avatar, :avatar_cache])
      change_password = true
      if params[:user][:password].blank?
        params[:user].delete("password")
        params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
        new_params = params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :admin, :approved, :tag_list, profile_attributes: [:anrede, :titel,  :vorname, :nachname, :user_id, :kanzlei, :kanlei_nr, :straße, :straße_nr, :plz, :stadt, :land, :telefon, :avatar, :avatar_cache])
        change_password = false
      end

      @user = User.find(current_user.id)

      is_valid = false

      if change_password
        is_valid = @user.update_with_password(new_params)
      else
        is_valid = @user.update_without_password(new_params)
      end

      if is_valid
        set_flash_message :notice, :updated
        sign_in @user, :bypass => true
        redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
      else
        render "edit"
      end
    end
  end


  protected

  def send_welcome_mail
    if @user.save
    UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    end
  end


end
```

And the request are:

```
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"G7lzhNmFyRBd3aSxQmmqGQG6IwAFywSdjPBoMFFIwYY=", "user"=>{"profile_attributes"=>{"id"=>"83", "anrede"=>"Herr", "titel"=>"", "vorname"=>"Furkan", "nachname"=>"Adigüzel", "kanzlei"=>"cnjw", "kanlei_nr"=>"njewin", "straße"=>"Korallusring", "straße_nr"=>"5", "plz"=>"21109", "stadt"=>"Hamburg", "land"=>"Deutschland", "telefon"=>"21374891207"}, "username"=>"Furkan", "tag_list"=>["", "1", "2"], "email"=>"Furkan_adiguezel@hotmail.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Update"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 20  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: id
Unpermitted parameters: tag_list
Unpermitted parameters: id
Unpermitted parameters: tag_list, current_password
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 20]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Profile Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 20]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = ?  [["id", 83]]
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('Furkan') AND "users"."id" != 20) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("anrede", "created_at", "kanlei_nr", "kanzlei", "land", "nachname", "plz", "stadt", "straße", "straße_nr", "telefon", "titel", "updated_at", "user_id", "vorname") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["anrede", "Herr"], ["created_at", "2014-06-14 14:39:30.626720"], ["kanlei_nr", "njewin"], ["kanzlei", "cnjw"], ["land", "Deutschland"], ["nachname", "Adigüzel"], ["plz", "21109"], ["stadt", "Hamburg"], ["straße", "Korallusring"], ["straße_nr", "5"], ["telefon", "21374891207"], ["titel", ""], ["updated_at", "2014-06-14 14:39:30.626720"], ["user_id", 20], ["vorname", "Furkan"]]
   (1.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 68ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-14 16:39:30 +0200
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  Rendered visitors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 20  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 20]]
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (7.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (8.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 42ms (Views: 41.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: yes undefined method `map' for :id:Symbol

Comment: Shouldn't this field `taggings_id` just be `tag_id`?

Comment: no got the same Error. I believe, thats an issue with :id

Comment: In which table you have `taggings_id` field?

Comment: And also post your related controller code.

Comment: Now I changed my view the error dessapears, I update my code and the controller

Comment: Now error disappeared? everything works now?

Comment: no I got a new Error undefined method `strip' for ["", "2"]:Array

Comment: Where is that error pointing to?